# ASP.NET Repeater will not show data

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, datasource, repeater

I have an ASP.Net Repeater I want to use to show From and Text from a dataset and I want to add it programmically.  I have all the data in a dataset and can use that and I have verified the correct number for datarows when it loads so the data is their it is just not showing.  What have I missed?.

```
Dim data As New Data
Dim ds As New DataSet
ds = data.LOADALL()
Dim drMsg() As DataRow = ds.Tables("MESSAGESYSTEM").Select("TOID='101'")
repeatMessages.DatagSource = drMsg
```

Now on the html side I have:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repeatMessages" runat="server" >
    <HeaderTemplate>
              <table>
              <tr>
                 <th>From</th>
                 <th>Sublect</th>
              </tr>
          </HeaderTemplate>
          <ItemTemplate>
          <tr>
              <td bgcolor="#CCFFCC">
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" text='<%# Eval("FROMID") %>' />
              </td>
              <td bgcolor="#CCFFCC">
                  <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label2" text='<%# Eval("MESSAGETEXT") %>' />
              </td>
          </tr>
          </ItemTemplate>
          <FooterTemplate>
              </table>
          </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

How can I fix this code to show the data in the Message table?

Comment: You should show us the `LOADALL`-function. Does the table contain the columns `FROMID` and `MESSAGETEXT`? Besides you have a typo: `repeatMessages.DatagSource = drMsg`, that would not even compile. I'm also missing the `repeatMessages.DataBind`. Are you doing this only `If Not Page.IsPostBack` what would be correct?

Comment: Yes the data is being loaded by the load function.  their are 2 rows that are returned and they do have those column names.  And yes this occurs withing a If not postback clause.

Comment: As @Tim is saying, call `repeatMessages.DataBind()` after assigning the data source.

Comment: @JPJedi try to add the repeatMessages.DataBind();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try calling `repeatMessages.DataBind()`. All you are doing is assigning the source but you haven't told the program to do something with the data.